# React Native Tab Navigator first tab is focused by default

Tags: react-native, tabnavigator, react-navigation-bottom-tab, react-native-tabnavigator

I'm using React Native BottomTabNavigator.

Example:

```html
<Tab.Navigator tabBarOptions={tabBarOptions} screenOptions={screenOptions}>
  <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
  <Tab.Screen name="Saved" component={Saved} />
  <Tab.Screen name="Map" component={Map} />
  <Tab.Screen name="Profile" component={Profile} />
</Tab.Navigator>
```

I want to make the last tab focused instead of the first.
I can't find any option in the documentation.

It should be something like options={{ focused: true }}
Or maybe it's not implemented at all

Comment: set a ```initialRouteName``` prop for your tab navigator.

Comment: That's it, Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
<Tab.Navigator initialRouteName={"Your Initial Screen Name"}
...>
</Tab.Navigator>
```